# Rspec: a way to include let helpers into different specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

`let` and `let!` provide useful functionality. Sometimes it might be necessary to include same helpers in different specs (DRY). For example, a set of lets are included in some way into every request spec. Is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`shared_context`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context)

Comment: Either that or just roll it up into a regular module which you can include into your specs.

Comment: @max it will raise an error

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a `shared_context`:

```
# shared_stuff.rb
shared_context "shared stuff" do
  let(:shared_let) { "foo" }
end
```

and use it in various examples:

```
# example.rb
require_relative "shared_stuff.rb"

describe "an example" do
  include_context "shared stuff"

  it "has access to shared lets" do
    expect(shared_let).to eq("foo")
  end
end
```

Output:

```
$ rspec example.rb                                                                                              
an example
  has access to shared lets

Finished in 0.00076 seconds (files took 0.11233 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Right, shared contexts may also be implicitly included with matching metadata - useful thing when we need to include them into definite kind of specs.